# Application on another system crashes on startup without error message for sudo, Segmentation Fault for non-sudo

Tags: c++, crash, g++, error-reporting, websocket++

I have written a websocket++ server on Ubuntu 13.10 and am trying to execute it on Linux Mint 16.

I have installed all dependencies, and the first line under `main` is a `cout` which never fires.

This is the compile command:

```
g++ -o Dgn Dgn.cpp ed25519-donna-master/ed25519.o 
  -Og -std=c++0x -I ~/Dgn -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ -D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ 
  -lboost_regex -lboost_system -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -pthread -lpqxx 
  -lboost_thread -ljson_spirit -lgmp -lgmpxx
```

If I execute with `sudo` to use restricted ports, it fails immediately without error returning to the command line.

If I execute without `sudo`, is prints `Segmentation Fault` and fails immediately to the command line.

The directories in `~/Dgn` are present on the new system.

I did a quick, simple test and checked to see if a basic websocket++ example could compile and execute normally, and it was successful.

Both systems are 64-bit.  The only difference are the distros, but Linux Mint 16 is based upon Ubuntu 13.10, and all commands to setup were identical.

How can this be compiled so that it can execute on another system?

---

As a further test, I compiled it on the new system, and it works.

Is it not possible to compile on one system and run on another?

### GDB

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de58da in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: helps to ftp binary files as...binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `cout` line never fires (I assume it has `<< std::endl`) means that the crash happens in a static object constructor. The most straightforward way to debug is to allow core dump (see `man limits`) and inspect the dump with gdb. So far that's all I can think of. More details will help.

Comment: Thank you!  I've posted the `gdb` output.  Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Not really, but it is a good start. Next step is to type `where` or `bt` at the gdb prompt.

Comment: Oh well, I'll just compile for both.  Thank you so much!